# PHP login algorithm not redirecting to next page (unsure on connection to database)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am setting up a login page to take a users username and password then check that against a local database, however nothing is echoing form the database connection and there is no redirecting to the next page 'welcome.php' happening.

I have already tried many different ways of connecting to the local database and redirecting to different pages with different methods, none of which gave any error message or worked. using XAMPP Apache and mySQL modules to provide the local server.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Login']))
{

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password','budget');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

session_start();

$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= sha1($_POST['password']);

$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT accounts.username, passwords.password_hash
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN passwords ON accounts.account_id = passwords.account_id
WHERE accounts.username = '$username' AND password_hash = '$password';");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace(welcome.php); 
</script>;
<?php
mysql_close($link); 
}
}

?>
```

I expect it to redirect to 'welcome.php' but instead it just refreshes the same page and nothing is echoed or given as an error

Comment: if you have default xampp installation, try changing this line **$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password','budget');** to this **$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','budget');** and also change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: ***You shouldn't use [SHA1 password hashes](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)***  or ***[MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 2):

**What isn't working?**
Your JavaScript `location.replace` method needs a string as an input, you're not giving it that (as the input value is not quoted). It would be `window.location.replace('welcome.php');` instead.

**How to solve it?**
The better solution is to redirect in PHP instead of in JavaScript, using `header()`.

**Additional remarks**
I took the liberty of converting your code to use `mysqli_` instead of the old, outdated and deprecated `mysqli_` library. With this, you can use a prepared statement, as I have shown below. Use this approach for *all your queries*, bind the parameters through placeholders.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','budget');
    if ($link->connection_errno) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . $con->error);
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT a.username, p.password_hash
                            FROM accounts a 
                            INNER JOIN passwords p 
                               ON a.account_id = a.account_id
                            WHERE a.username = ? 
                              AND p.password_hash = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->bind_result($resultUsername, $resultPassword);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**What's next?**
Fix your passwords. Using `sha1()` is highly insecure for passwords, look into using `passwords_hash()`/`password_verify()` instead.

Comment: can't we use any other hashing, like sha256 or sha512 with php? or RSA or something?

Comment: I recommend `password_hash()`, that's designed particularly for storing and verifying passwords. It's quite easy to use as well. But PHP has sha256, sha512 if that's what you're asking, but I wouldn't use it for passwords.

Comment: why is that? aren't they better than sha1? and what about some others like RSA or whirlpool?

Comment: I wouldn't say SHA256 or SHA512 is secure enough for passwords. Something like bcrypt would be, that's what `password_hash()` is based on.

Comment: from the word prepare onward it seems the code is appearing in the actual page itself rather than being ran on the server, any idea what I am doing wrong? @Qirel

Answer (score 1):

You need to add single quote around `welcome.php`

As `welcome.php` is neither a JavaScript keyword like `this` nor a number, single quote is mandatory also it is not a variable/object.

JS considers `welcome` as object and `php` as its method in `welcome.php`

Without it, a JavaScript error will be displayed:

> ReferenceError: welcome is not defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace(welcome.php); 
</script>
```

Also, there is no need of semi-colon `;`.

JavaScript redirect without any condition.

Comment: Okay so that worked, thank you. However it now instantly validates the user without any input and takes he client instantly to the welcome page. any idea how to fix this? @pupil

Comment: Javascript redirection is not preferred. You should use PHP's `header("Location:welcome.php")` instead.